# Find fit approximation for recursive formula where f(n)=(a^n)(logn)^(a-1)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I am trying to solve this question:

> Find fit approximation for the following formula:
>
> ```
> T(1) = c > 0
> T(n) = 8T(n/4) + n^(a)*(logn)^(a - 1)
> a >= 1
> ```
>
> Hint: separate for 3 different cases

It find out that when `a=1.5`, then it's the second case of the master theorem. I couldn't use this theorem when `a <= 1 < 1.5` and when `a>1.5`.
I would like to have a direction for how to approach this question.

Comment: You should probably post such questions here: https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

From [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), as `c = log_4(8) = 1.5`, if `a = 1.5` and `f(n) = \Theta(n^c log^k(n))` whcih `k > -1` (case 2), `T(n) = n^(1.5) * log(n)^2`.

Hence, if `a > 1.5`, as `f(n) = Omega(n^c)`, `T(n) = \Theta(n^a log(n)^(a-1)` (case 3).

For `1 <= a <1.5`, as `f(n) = o(n^1.5)`, we can say `T(n) = \Theta(n^1.5)` (case1).

Comment: can you please explain the second and third rows? why if a > 1.5 then f(n) = Omega(n^c)?

Comment: how do you compare n^1.5 and n^(a)*(logn)^(a-1)?

Comment: @MyNick all of them are the case of Master Theorem.